# C# WinForms slightly different vertical spacing between RichTextBox text

Tags: c#, winforms, fonts, richtextbox, spacing

I'm trying to add line numbers to a homemade editor via a split view holding two RichTextBoxes. The one on the left is line numbers, and the one on the right is the actual text. However, I am seeing the line numbers gradually getting out of sync with the text. I'm not sure how accurate measuring via screenshot is, but despite using the same fonts, the line numbering TextBox has a vertical spacing between characters of 7 pixels, while the vertical spacing between characters in the main editor pane is 6. The actual characters themselves have the same height in both views.

I'm setting everything up with the following code

```
public class RTLSourceView : SplitContainer
{
    public RTLSourceView(string filename)
    {
        DoubleBuffered = true;
        Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        
        RtlRichTextBox rtb = new RtlRichTextBox();
        rtb.Text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filename);
        rtb.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        rtb.ForeColor = Color.White;
        rtb.BackColor = Color.Black;
        rtb.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        rtb.VScroll += richTextBox1_VScroll;
        Panel2.Controls.Add(rtb);

        RichTextBox line_numbers = new RichTextBox();
        line_numbers.Multiline = true;
        line_numbers.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        line_numbers.WordWrap = false;
        line_numbers.ReadOnly = true;
        line_numbers.ForeColor = Color.White;
        line_numbers.BackColor = Color.Black;
        line_numbers.SelectionLength = 0;
        line_numbers.SizeChanged += onSizeChange;
        line_numbers.Font = rtb.Font;
        line_numbers.ScrollBars = RichTextBoxScrollBars.None;
        Panel1.Controls.Add(line_numbers);
```

I'm setting line_numbers.Font to rtb.Font, and that indeed look ok in the debugger. I'm more of a SystemVerilog programmer than a C# one, so I am probably missing some obvious setting that everyone else knows, but I am curious what might make two RichTextBoxes with the same font attached to the same split panel have two different font spacings

[image]

Comment: The two Controls have different Fonts. Set the Font explicitly, before it's inherited from the Parent

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer. I had noticed the difference in the screenshot, so I added the code

rtb.Font = new Font(FontFamily.GenericMonospace, rtb.Font.Size);
line_numbers.Font = new Font(FontFamily.GenericMonospace, rtb.Font.Size);

To the original posted code snippet, but the fonts still look different. Now I am wondering if the font is being overwritten somewhere else, or there is a missing step in setting the font. Or maybe I am not sure when it's inherited from the parent

Answer (score 1):

It might get a little tricky because there's more than just the font involved. For example, line spacing comes into play since every CR in the rtf is going to be a new `/par`.

[image: screenshot]

---

Here's a first pass at a scheme that calculates the position of characters and makes a new line label when the Y coordinate changes.

```
public partial class RichTextBoxEx : UserControl
{
    const int 
        MAX_VISIBLE_LINES = 100,
        LINE_LABEL_HEIGHT = 20;
    public RichTextBoxEx()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_VISIBLE_LINES; i++)
        {
            panel.Controls.Add(new Label
            {
                Name = $"label{i}",
                Text = "Placeholder",
                Location = new Point(0, i * LINE_LABEL_HEIGHT),
                TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft,
                Size = new Size(panel.Width, LINE_LABEL_HEIGHT),
                AutoSize = false,
            });
        }
        _labels = panel.Controls.OfType<Label>().ToArray();
    }
    private readonly Label[] _labels;
    protected override void OnCreateControl()
    {
        base.OnCreateControl();
        richTextBox.VScroll += recalc;
        richTextBox.TextChanged += recalc;
        richTextBox.Rtf = rtf;
    }

    private void recalc(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int charIndex = richTextBox
        .GetLineFromCharIndex(
            richTextBox.GetCharIndexFromPosition(Point.Empty));

        int y, delta, cum = 0, prevY = 0;
        int labelIndex = 0;
        while(charIndex < richTextBox.Text.Length)
        {
            Point pos = richTextBox.GetPositionFromCharIndex(charIndex);
            y = pos.Y;
            if (!y.Equals(prevY))
            {
                delta = y - prevY;
                cum += delta;
                Debug.WriteLine($"{prevY} {y} {delta} {cum}");
                prevY = y;
                _labels[labelIndex].Top = cum;
                _labels[labelIndex].Visible = true;
                _labels[labelIndex].Text = $"{labelIndex + 1}";
                labelIndex++;
            }
            charIndex++;
        }
        while (labelIndex < MAX_VISIBLE_LINES)
        {
            _labels[labelIndex++].Visible = false;
        }
    }

    const string rtf =
@"{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\nouicompat\deflang1033{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Calibri;}}
{\*\generator Riched20 10.0.22621}\viewkind4\uc1 
\pard\sa200\sl276\slmult1\f0\fs22\lang9 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed pellentesque, odio ac posuere vehicula, risus arcu cursus nunc, a varius nisi lectus fermentum quam. Maecenas dignissim metus sed felis sodales suscipit. Aliquam sagittis pharetra massa, eu hendrerit erat maximus non. Nulla facilisi. Quisque libero urna, vulputate ut maximus in, sodales vitae mi. \par
\b\fs40 Suspendisse\b0\fs22  \par
In est metus. Donec id turpis lorem. Curabitur id ipsum bibendum, fringilla eros vel, vulputate enim. Pellentesque nec sem a sem rhoncus ultrices. Quisque at purus a odio semper sagittis a at tellus. \par
}";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@IVSoftware has a great answer as it takes in consideration that the font might be different on each line.

However if the font is the same for the whole document you need to assign an event to the `FontChange` event of `rtb` or assign the font to both RTBoxes when setting it from the dialog.

Your RTBoxes does not seem to not be available outside the scope of the `RTLSourceView(...)` method, so to get access to it you need to know the position of the control in the panel (or loop through the `Controls` property).
`RtlRichTextBox` might implement some default font on initialisation, in your code you have one `RtlRichTextBox` for `rtb` and a standard `RichTextBox` for `line_numbers`.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        //RichTextBox line_numbers;
        //RichTextBox rtb;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DoubleBuffered = true;
            Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

            RichTextBox rtb = new RichTextBox();
            //rtb.Text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filename);
            rtb.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            rtb.ForeColor = Color.White;
            rtb.BackColor = Color.Black;
            rtb.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            rtb.TextChanged += Rtb_TextChanged;
            rtb.FontChanged += Rtb_FontChanged;
            splitContainer1.Panel2.Controls.Add(rtb);

            RichTextBox line_numbers = new RichTextBox();
            line_numbers.Multiline = true;
            line_numbers.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            line_numbers.WordWrap = false;
            line_numbers.ReadOnly = true;
            line_numbers.ForeColor = Color.White;
            line_numbers.BackColor = Color.Black;
            line_numbers.SelectionLength = 0;
            line_numbers.Font = rtb.Font;
            line_numbers.ScrollBars = RichTextBoxScrollBars.None;
            splitContainer1.Panel1.Controls.Add(line_numbers);
        }

        private void Rtb_FontChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (sender is RichTextBox rtb)
            {
                if (splitContainer1.Panel1.Controls[0] is RichTextBox line_numbers)
                {
                    line_numbers.Font = rtb.Font;
                }
            }
        }

        private void Rtb_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (sender is RichTextBox rtb)
            {
                if (splitContainer1.Panel1.Controls[0] is RichTextBox line_numbers)
                {
                    line_numbers.Clear();
                    for (int i = 0; i < rtb.Lines.Length; i++)
                    {
                        line_numbers.Text += $"{i + 1}{Environment.NewLine}";
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (fontDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                if (splitContainer1.Panel2.Controls[0] is RichTextBox rtb)
                {
                    rtb.Font = fontDialog1.Font;
                }
            }
        }
    
    }
```

The above code is just a form with a button for calling the `FontDialog.ShowDialog()` and the split panels.

[image]